# unable to use fork() in recursion?

Tags: c, linux, recursion, fork

I have got programming assignment to merge to arrays using binary insertion search(ie., in sorted order) using fork() system call in **C** in linux based OS.

I have done it **WITHOUT** using fork() and its working fine. Now I want to use fork() system call in it. I have read about fork() system call but, I am unable to use it in my program. Please help me out!

Comment: Yeah we would like to help, but where to start?

Comment: Where should I use fork() in my program. Means what should I replace fork() with? What is the main idea?

Comment: show some code, it may help

Comment: From what you've written, it sounds like you can just add 'if(fork()==0) exit();` at the top of the code you currently have.

Comment: @WilliamPursell LOL, be nice!

Comment: Sorry everyone for not putting the code. I have added the code. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @user3870357 fork() spawns a new child process that has a copy of its parent's memory and program and shares most open file descriptors.  I'm not sure what your instructor has in mind for exploiting fork() to help merge two arrays.

Comment: Your base code looks wrong to me.  When you fail to find a match with binSearch() you return -1, which causes sort() to insert the unmatched item at the beginning of your sorted partition.  Instead, you want to return l or r as appropriate.

Comment: @jschultz410 Thanks. Please check the code now! 
I just need help in fork(), how to put fork() in this program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use fork() to have a child process execute each binary search and have the child return the insertion point to the parent through a pipe (or the child's exit status if the array will always be 255 elements or smaller).

That's the only thing I can see that makes any sense at all and you'd never do this in the real world -- only as an exercise to get a feel for fork().

Basically, you'd call fork() right before binSearch(). The child would execute the binSearch() and return the insertion point through a pipe (or its exit code). Meanwhile, the parent would wait for the insertion point result and then perform the insert.

A way to use fork() that **might** make a bit more sense would be to break the array to be sorted in half, with each half to be recursively sorted by a different child process that communicates their sorted half back through a pipe that only goes to their parent.  The parent merges the two sorted halves together using merge sort and communicates the result up to its parent.  The ultimate parent outputs the sorted array.  That will exploit parallelism but in exchange for significant amounts of inter-process communication.